# {% if %} tag for showing strikethrough

Tags: django-templates

Let's have a DetailView with a model Person. Let's suppose year_of_birth = None for this Person instance.

Can Django template language organize something like this?

```
{% with "---" as strikethrough %}

<p>Year of birth:  {% object.year_of_birth or strikethrough %}

{% endwith %}
```

I've experimented with curly brackets. Anyway I get something like this:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag on line 9: '{strikethrough}', expected 'endwith'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Well, is the idea of using 'or' in such case viable or I must use {% if %} tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#default)
or [default_if_none](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none) template tag:

```
...
<p>Year of birth: {% object.year_of_birth|default:strikethrough %}</p>
...
```

Also take a look at [firstof](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#firstof) for logic with more than two options.